# How to call Swift class methods from objective C Class?

Tags: objective-c, swift

In My App used both swift and objective c classes. I have to import Swift delegate protocol  in objective c class .when i tried to import(@implementation SampleViewController) delegate protocol, i am getting error "@implementation declaration cannot be protocol "

Comment: use bridging header

Comment: Visit https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/swift-and-objective-c-interoperability-2add8e6d6887 Read this for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use Swift methods you need to import a header file which is generally named to YourProductName-Swift.h and bingo you can use the swift classes, their properties and methods.

You can find the name of this header file in you Target>Build Settings>Swift Compiler - General>Objective-C generated Interface Header Name.

[image: Objective-C generated Interface Header Name]

Comment: Thanks, i have to use delegate methods. when i tried to import Delegate protocol (<BluetoothDelegate>) showing error (Cannot find protocol declaration for 'BluetoothDelegate). how to use delegate methods from swift classes.

Comment: #import <yourprojectname-Swift.h> if the BluetoohDelegate is written in swift and you will be able to use it in objective-c.

Comment: I imported #import <yourprojectname-Swift.h>. i can creating instances for swift class. i can able to call methods using instance. but when i used delegate methods in objective c class its not being called.

Comment: Make the protocol objective-c compliant by placing "@objc" before the protocol declaration. for example: @objc protocol Testable { //your rules. }

Comment: if i use  @objc protocol BluetoothSerialDelegate {
   
    func serialDidChangeState()                                    }                                                                      extension BluetoothSerialDelegate                              {
    func serialDidReceiveString(_ message: String) {}  it is showing error (Non-'@objc' method 'serialDidReceiveString' does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol 'BluetoothSerialDelegate').

Comment: @objc protocol Testable {
    
    func testPrint()
}

extension Testable {

    func testPrint() {
    }
}
work fine in my case i am able to use it in objective-c class as well.

Comment: But for me it is showing this error (Non-'@objc' method  does not satisfy requirement of '@objc' protocol).